# How to close all drivers in case of parallel run using testng selenium with java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to *Selenium(Java)* and using *TestNG* framework.I am using factory with data provider in the code.But in case of parallel execution , not able to close all the drivers.Find below my test code.Please advise.

```
public class FactoryDataProvider {

    private String param;
    WebDriver driver =null;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dataMethod")
    public FactoryDataProvider(String param) {
        this.param = param;


    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] dataMethod() {
        return  new Object[][] {
                new Object[] { "http://www.yahoo.com" }, 
               new Object[] { "http://www.google.com" } } ;
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeTest(){
        System.out.println("Before Test executed : ");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }


  @Test
    public void testMethodOne() {
        System.out.println("Thread ID :"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Test method one output: " + param);
        driver.get(param);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodTwo() {
        System.out.println("Thread ID :"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Test method two output: " + param);
        driver.get(param);
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly happening?

Comment: Only one instance of driver get closed if we run test in parallel. What I want is to close all the driver instances once all test methods are run.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use either **AfterMethod** or **AfterClass** (depending on what you really need).

With any of the above, in the end, there is no driver window hanging.

[image]

With **AfterTest**, the window is not closed.

Comment: I don't want to use @AfterMethod as I am executing all test methods of a suite in same driver.

Comment: With @AfterTest and AfterClass , it is closing only one driver instance.

Comment: My bad..With the use of @AfterClass , it just got resolved.Thanks.